# There exists $h:P\longrightarrow M$ such that $fh=g\Leftrightarrow \textrm{Im}(g)\subseteq \textrm{Im}(f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $P$, $M$ and $N$ three left modules over $R$. Futhermore, suppose $P$ is **projetive**. Let $f\in \textrm{Hom}_R(M, N)$ and $g\in\textrm{Hom}_R(P, N)$.

How can I show there exists $h\in \textrm{Hom}_R(P, M)$ such that $fh=g$ if and only if $\textrm{Im}(g)\subseteq \textrm{Im}(f)$?

**Obs.** The implication $(\Rightarrow)$ is immediate. For the converse, I had got nowhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is proved by restricting the codomains of the maps $f$ and $g$ to $\textrm{Im}(f)$.  This way, we get morphisms (which I denote by the same symbols)
$$ f\in\textrm{Hom}_R (M,\textrm{Im}(f)) $$
and
$$ g\in\textrm{Hom}_R (P,\textrm{Im}(f)). $$
Note that $g$ can be restricted in this way only because $\textrm{Im}(g)$ is contained in $\textrm{Im}(f)$; we view the restriction as the composition of $g:P\to \textrm{Im}(g)$ and of the inclusion $\textrm{Im}(g) \to \textrm{Im}(f)$.

Now, this restriction of $f$ is surjective onto $\textrm{Im}(f)$, so the fact that $P$ is projective implies the existence of $h\in \textrm{Hom}_R(P, M)$ such that $fh=g$.